# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'crypt19' (= 1.2.1) in any repository while running with rails 3.2.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am  having ruby version *ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]* which i am using for *Rails 3.0*.
Now i am having a project with rails version *'2.3.18'*. and **ree-1.8.7-2012.02** [ x86_64 ].
bundle install and rake db:create is working fine and when I run rake db:migrate i am getting the following notice:

```
Missing these required gems:
  crypt19  = 1.2.1

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.374 at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.8.15 at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@community_clean, /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

And when I run the above command, i am getting error as:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'crypt19' (= 1.2.1) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: crypt, crypt3, crypto, cryptor, cryptsy
```

and you can see in below Gemfile that i am comment **crypt19**.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '2.3.18'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '2.0.4'
gem 'acts_as_archive', '0.4.0'
gem 'acts_as_dropdown', '2.0.3'
gem 'also_migrate', '0.3.5'
gem 'axlsx', '1.3.5'
#gem 'crypt19', '1.2.1'
gem 'bitly', '0.5.1'
gem 'builder', '3.0.0'
gem 'capistrano', '2.5.18'
gem 'capistrano-ext', '1.2.1'
gem 'chronic', '0.3.0'
gem 'command-t', '1.2.1'
gem 'daemons', '1.0.10'
gem 'database_cleaner', '0.6.0'
gem 'diff-lcs', '1.1.2'
gem 'eventmachine', '0.12.10'
gem 'github-markup', '0.5.3'
gem 'hashie', '0.2.0'
gem 'hoe', '2.5.0'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier', '2.4.2'
gem 'htmlentities', '4.3.1'
gem 'httparty', '0.5.2'
gem 'i18n', '0.6.0'
gem 'json_pure', '1.4.6'
gem 'mail', '2.3.0'
gem 'memcache-client', '1.8.5'
# gem 'memcached', '0.19.7'
gem 'mime-types', '1.16'
gem 'mocha', '0.9.10'
gem 'mogli', '0.0.16'
gem 'money', '2.1.5'
gem 'mover', '0.3.6'
gem 'oauth', '0.4.7'
gem 'polyglot', '0.3.1'
gem 'pony', '1.3'
gem 'powder', '0.1.7'
gem 'prawn', '0.8.4'
gem 'prawn-core', '0.8.4'
gem 'prawn-layout', '0.8.4'
gem 'prawn-security', '0.8.4'
gem 'rack', '1.1.6'
gem 'rack-rewrite', '1.0.2'
gem 'rack-test', '0.5.6'
# gem 'rmagick', '2.13.1'
gem 'rspec', '1.3.1'
gem 'rspec-rails', '1.3.3'
gem 'ruby-hmac', '0.4.0'
gem 'rubyzip', '0.9.9'
gem 'rvm', '1.11.3.5'
gem 'thor', '0.14.6'
gem 'tzinfo', '0.3.16'
gem 'validatable', '1.6.7'
gem 'webrat', '0.7.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '2.2.2'
gem 'xml-simple', '1.0.12'
gem 'yajl-ruby', '0.7.8'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

Please pull me out of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of February of 2013, the crypt19 gem vanished from rubygems. Although, the gem is still hosted on github, so you can specify manually the git repository from where to fetch the gem:

```
gem 'crypt19-rb', :git => 'https://github.com/coffeejunk/crypt19.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Also, make sure you specify the correct gem version to be used, since the above gem's version is 1.3.1, instead of 1.2.1 . In your `environment.rb` file, add the following line (or replace it with the good version):

```
config.gem 'crypt19-rb', :version => '1.3.1'
```

As to why the bundler tries to install your gem even though it's commented, I'm not sure I can explain. Perhaps it's because you're missing a space? But that's odd.

Comment: If I added **gem 'crypt19', :git => 'https://github.com/coupa/crypt19.git', :branch => 'master'** and run bundle install i am getting error as `Could not find gem 'crypt19 (>= 0) ruby' in https://github.com/coupa/crypt19.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'crypt19 (>= 0) ruby'`

Comment: Did you try its mirror? `gem 'crypt19', :git => 'https://github.com/coffeejunk/crypt19.git'; :branch => 'master'`. It's a little more recent, so it may work. If it doesn't, tell me, I'll try to find another solution.

Comment: Same issue BishopBarber

Comment: Oops, in coffejunk/crypt19's gemspec, you can see the name is not `crypt19`, but `crypt19-rb`. The name you specify in your gemfile must match the name specified in the gem's gemspec. If you try `gem 'crypt19-rb', :git => 'https://github.com/coffeejunk/crypt19.git', :branch => 'master'`, it should work.

Comment: I added the same in Gemfile and bundle install, rake db:create and when I run rake db:migrate, i am getting the error as `Missing these required gems:
  crypt19  = 1.2.1

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.374 at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.8.15 at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@community_clean, /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.`

Comment: Try executing `gem list | grep crypt` and tell me what is the output?

Comment: I am getting `crypt (2.0)
crypt19-rb (1.3.1)
crypt3 (1.1.6)
`

Comment: I see.. the installed gem version is 1.3.1 and Rails is looking for v1.2.1 . In your environment.rb file, add this line: `config.gem 'crypt19-rb', :version => '1.3.1'`, or replace it with the good version number if the line already exists.